# Airflow command gives error due to missing api_auth.deny_all

Tags: python, airflow

On our staging machine, running any `airflow` command gives error:

```
[2018-09-01 16:12:55,938] {__init__.py:37} CRITICAL - Cannot import api_auth.deny_all for API authentication due to: No module named api_auth.deny_all
```

`api_auth` seems to come along with airflow, as I tried `pip install api_auth` and could not find a lib.

On the same machine, I tried to reinstall a fresh clean airflow using `virtualenv` and `pip install airflow`, and still get this error. 
I tried again on my own laptop and airflow works fine. So I suspect it is probably due to the historical `~/airflow/airflow.cfg` on the staging machine.

I am not familiar with the `airflow.cfg` settings, and cannot find any clue on Google.
Anyone know what may cause the issue and how to resolve?

Comment: How did you install Airflow? Can you verify that the database was initialized?

Answer (score 0):

You are installing a wrong version of Apache Airflow.

Please install Airflow using the following:

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

instead of

```
pip install airflow
```

Airflow package has been renamed to `apache-airflow` since 1.8.0

Check the following link for documentation:

https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html#getting-airflow